# how to get the landing page URL after redirections using axios

Tags: node.js, axios

Using NodeJS, If I use axios with maxRedirects = 5, If I type a URL that will be redirected to another URL, how can I get the URL from the final landing page?
In HTTP headers, when there is an HTTP 200 code, there is no header field for the landing page.

Example: if I use:

```
axios.get('http://stackoverflow.com/',config)
.then(function(response) { console.log(response);}
```

axios will automatically redirect to https://stackoverflow.com. So, how can get the final URL value "https://stackoverflow.com"?

Should I investigate in the returned object "response" and recreate the full url from domain and URI?

Answer (score 21):

Here is my quick and dirty solution on NodeJS. The starting URL is `http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/47444251/how-to-get-the-landing-page-url-after-redirections-using-axios` , the final landing URL is
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444251/how-to-get-the-landing-page-url-after-redirections-using-axios` Please find the trick below to get the landing URL.

```
axios.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/47444251/how-to-get-the-landing-page-url-after-redirections-using-axios').then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.request.res.responseUrl);
     }).catch(function(no200){
      console.error("404, 400, and other events");
     
    });
```

response.request.res.responseURL is the right field in the JSON object that is returned by axios. If you run axios from a browser use     console.log(response.request.responseURL);

Comment: I guess this only works when used from Node but not from the browser?

Comment: Can anyone tell that how can i redirect to URL present inside "response.request.res.responseUrl"

Answer (score 19):

I solved it by getting it from:

```
response.request.res.responseUrl
```

The [Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968706/nicolas-gu%C3%A9rinet) answer failed to get the port (like `localhost:8080`)

Comment: thank you, I guess axios was updated since the time I posted the initial response and I updated it.

Comment: Can anyone tell that how can i redirect to URL present inside "response.request.res.responseUrl"

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by getting it from:

```
response.request.responseURL
```

The [MrFabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116863/mrfabio)'s answer failed for me.